# C# Apply changes made to copied DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, copy, gridcontrol

**Hello everyone!**

I stumbled upon a problem while trying to display and edit data in multiple GridControls (DataGridViews) using multiple DataTables.

I have a main DataTable that stores data about Users (just an example) and a set of another DataTables that store different data (also about users).

The way I am displaying them now is as follows: All additional DataTables have a „UserId” column and when the row is clicked in main GridControl (Users), the data for other GridControls is copied using

```
DataTable.Select(„UserId = …”)
```

method and then the data for only selected user is being displayed in GridControl. The DataTable with full data is being stored in a different variable and each time the MainGrid row is clicked, the full data is used to generate DataTable for selected user.

The displaying data works okay, but when it comes to editing those additional GridControls, there are some problems. For editing them I am using SqlDataAdapters that generate full DataTable for each of additional tables and when the save button is clicked, they simply update the database.

**The problem is that after I use**

```
DataTable.Select(“UserId = …”)
```

**if I edit the new table, the full table is not going to be affected by that.**

On the other hand, I can’t just do

```
DataTable _NewTable = _OldTable
```

because then if I try to remove rows with other User's data that I don't want to display, they’re going to be completely removed from the full DataTable.

As I am using a DevExpress controls, I could just set the DataSource of GridControl to the full table and apply a filter on the GridControl, but it would make filtering data more difficult for end user.

Do you have an idea on how to solve that problem so I can edit those "small" DataTables and then somehow update those changed rows in the full DataTable and be able to use SqlDataAdapter?

Thanks for help and sorry if I confused you!

Comment: Refresh full table from database after changes are made.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for reply, It would help if I wanted to save rows after they lose focus, but I want to save when the button is clicked to allow the end user to cancel changes if needed. I need to keep the original DataTable with all changes until the save button is clicked and then just use SqlDataAdapter to update changes to database.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too.  You want to update screen, but keep original datatable until user verifies updates.  So you must keep two copies of the DataTable.  One before changes and one after changes.  You can switch the GridControl  data source (binding) to point to either of the two DataTables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved by @Vlad using DataView as data source for additional grid controls with row filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think u must not copy values the child tables and pass it via reference into parent grid. Read about difference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx). So then you will change child grid, it will also change parent grid.

P.S. Please post all your code for more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks for reply, The problem for me is that at the same time I want to change the structure of copied DataTable (remove rows) while not changing the structure of the original DataTable. If I pass an original DataTable via reference and then try to remove rows to display only needed data, it will also remove rows from original DataTable.

Comment: You do not need remove rows, create DataView from you parent DataTable and filter it as shown here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.